Can Stackexchange see my email?
I recently created an account on Stackexchange and am concerned that Stackexchange has personal information. I needed to share my email to create this account. I do not want to get spam on my email and I don’t really want to share my email. Since I shared my email, can Stackexchange see it? More specifically, can moderators see my email?

Your email is hidden from the average user, but moderators do have the ability to access your email address. However, it is hidden behind a Personal Information access panel that we have to click a button to reveal. Moderator access to this panel is logged.

That's interesting. It's good that the average user cannot see my email. Even though I would prefer if nobody has it so that I don't get spam or malware, it is understandable that moderaters have access. Thank you for your answer. Also just out of curiousity, can anybody become a moderator? Or do you have to work for the company stackexchange?

@hotdog https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role
